Using r3f to update camera rotation/lookAt value
I’m pretty new to r3f and ThreeJS in general, I’m trying to achieve an effect where the camera starts on the outside of the model at [0,50,50] for instance, then animates to the centre of point at [0,20,0]. From here it will be able to spin around the centre point and look at different points on the model which is a ring around it. I have got the position animation down but for some reason I cannot figure out how to change the rotation/lookAt value (im not even 100% on which one I should be using), it always seems to be set to [0,0,0].
import { useThree, useFrame } from '@react-three/fiber';
import { OrbitControls, PerspectiveCamera } from '@react-three/drei';
import gsap from 'gsap';
import * as THREE from 'three';

function CameraController({ rotation, lookAtPosition, shouldAnimate, onAnimationComplete }) {
  const cameraRef = useRef();
  const controlsRef = useRef();
  const { set } = useThree();

  useEffect(() => {
    const lookAtVector = new THREE.Vector3(lookAtPosition);
    cameraRef.current.lookAt(...lookAtVector);
    console.log(cameraRef.current.position);
    console.log(cameraRef.current.rotation);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cameraRef.current) {
      set({ camera: cameraRef.current });
      const lookAtVector = new THREE.Vector3(...lookAtPosition);
      cameraRef.current.lookAt(lookAtVector);
      cameraRef.current.updateProjectionMatrix();

      console.log(cameraRef.current.rotation); 
    }
  }, [set, lookAtPosition]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (shouldAnimate && cameraRef.current) {
      gsap.to(cameraRef.current.position, {
        duration: 2,
        x: 0,
        y: 20,
        z: 20,
        ease: 'power2.out',
        onUpdate: () => {
          cameraRef.current.updateProjectionMatrix();
        },
        onComplete: () => {
          const lookAtVector = new THREE.Vector3(0, 20, 20);
          cameraRef.current.lookAt(lookAtVector);
          cameraRef.current.updateProjectionMatrix();
          console.log(cameraRef.current.rotation); 
          if (onAnimationComplete) onAnimationComplete();
        },
      });
    }
  }, [shouldAnimate, onAnimationComplete]);

  useFrame(() => {
    if (controlsRef.current) {
      controlsRef.current.update();
    }
  });

  return (
    <>
      <perspectiveCamera ref={cameraRef} position={[0,25, 0]}/>
      {cameraRef.current && (
        <OrbitControls
          ref={controlsRef}
          args={[cameraRef.current]}
          enableZoom={false}
          enablePan={true}
          enableRotate={true}
          minDistance={10}
          maxDistance={100}
          dampingFactor={0.2}
          rotateSpeed={0.5}
        /> 
      )} 
    </>
  );
}

export default CameraController;

You’ll see at the start i’m logging the positon and rotation to see where the camera is, this returns correct values that i’ve used to test it like [30,0,0] just to offset it and get a different results but there is no visible change. I feel like this is something I’m either approaching wrong or missing a trick here. Eventually I want to add in mouse tracking to look around but I seem to be running into a similar issue where nothing is updated despite values being logged.
